# Handle error resonse in angular and spring boot

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I have angular project that call spring boot backend using the following

```
    return this.http.post(url, request, {responseType: 'blob'})
      .pipe(catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          if (error.hasOwnProperty('error') && error.error != null) {
            return of(error.error);
          } else {
            return of(error);
          }
        }
```

and the reponse is of type blob.

if the backend throws error I am handling using spring boot 'ResponseEntityExceptionHandler'
but the error in the catch does not match what i throw because of parsing issues as the error is not of type blob
in other words error.hasOwnProperty('error') equals to false because what i sent wasn't parsed correctly !

my question, how can I keep the '{responseType: 'blob'}' with angular still able to parse the error correctly although it is not of type blob

Comment: What exactly is your question now?

Comment: Change the responseType to JSON like this: `'{responseType: json}'`

Now you could encode it with Base64 when you get a blob response in Spring Boot. Later in your Angular Code you can decode the Base64 string back into blob. On this way you can keep it as blob.